# Boolean in case using sets sql in the where clause

Tags: sql, case, where-clause, notin

I'm trying to use Not In with a boolean variable in the where to determine whether or not to search in a set for something. For example:

```
    Select
      BLAH
    FROM
      BLAH
    WHERE
      ...
      AND CASE WHEN @variable = 'false' THEN
           warningcode1 NOT IN (101,102,103)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
Select
      BLAH
    FROM
      BLAH
    WHERE
      ...
      AND (@variable <> 'false' OR warningcode1 NOT IN (101,102,103))
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use:

```
AND (@variable <> 'false' OR  warningcode1 NOT IN (101,102,103))
```

So the warningcode1  matters only if the variable = 'false', othwerwise it will be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

try this with if

```
AND IF( @variable = 'false' , warningcode1 NOT IN (101,102,103) , warningcode1 IN (101,102,103) )
```